# obtener registros que cumplan con una tabla en SQL ManagementStudio

Tags: sql, table

Estoy haciendo el filtro de una un E-comerce por lo que si necesito que traiga artículos que tengan el numero de características que solicito, por ejemplo , si quiero comprar una casa con 1 recamara , 2 estacionamientos , 1 baño  necesito enviar una tabla que tendría la primer columna para el ID de la característica y la segunda para el numero de dicha característica, en este caso la tabla seria 1-1,1-2,3-1 , y necesito que me devuelta únicamente los registros que cumplan esa tabla exacta  pero en su lugar mi consulta me devuelve las que cumplen con 1 recamara y ninguna de las otras o que cumplan con 2 estacionamientos y ninguna de las otras etc, etc. Esta es mi consulta en SQL

```
   ALTER procedure sp_pruebaFiltros (
    @busqueda NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,

        @caracteristicasPrincipales  caracteristicasPrincipales READONLY,
)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @consulta NVARCHAR(MAX)

        SET @consulta = 'SELECT Distinct IDPropiedad FROM V_FiltrosPropiedades_ecomm WHERE (@busqueda IS NULL OR Busqueda LIKE ''%'' + @busqueda + ''%'')'
        
        SET @consulta += ' AND ( IdCaractProp IN (SELECT IdCaractProp FROM  @caracteristicasPrincipales ))'
        SET @consulta  += ' AND ( NoElementos IN (SELECT NoElementos from  @caracteristicasPrincipales) )'
        SET @consulta += ' AND IDPropiedad IN (SELECT IDPropiedad FROM V_FiltrosPropiedades_ecomm AS fp WHERE fp.IDPropiedad = V_FiltrosPropiedades_ecomm.IDPropiedad AND fp.IdCaractProp IN (SELECT IdCaractProp FROM @caracteristicasPrincipales) GROUP BY IDPropiedad HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @caracteristicasPrincipales))';



    EXEC sp_executesql @consulta, @caracteristicasPrincipales [caracteristicasPrincipales] READONLY ',@caracteristicasPrincipales;

END
```

de forma resumida tengo esta tabla [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero necesito que me traiga unicamente los registro donde se cumple la siguiente tabla [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que en teoria solo deberia de ser el 12 pero me trae otros por que los otros cumplen con alguna  de las filas

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar, no necesitas usar código dinámico para esto. Lo único que hace es confundirte más y se puede hacer directamente con los parámetros. En segundo lugar, necesitas comparar todo el conjunto de datos y no valores individuales, por lo que podemos usar `EXCEPT`. Este operador traerá las filas de un conjunto de datos que no existan en otro. En este caso, queremos obtener las propiedades que tengan todas las características del parámetro, por lo que trataremos de que no nos regrese ni una fila y así tendremos nuestro filtro usando `NOT EXISTS`.

```
ALTER procedure sp_pruebaFiltros (
    @busqueda NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @caracteristicasPrincipales  caracteristicasPrincipales READONLY
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT Distinct IDPropiedad 
    FROM V_FiltrosPropiedades_ecomm fp
    WHERE (@busqueda IS NULL OR Busqueda LIKE '%' + @busqueda + '%') 
    AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT IdCaractProp, NoElementos
                    FROM @caracteristicasPrincipales cp
                    EXCEPT
                    SELECT IdCaractProp, NoElementos
                    FROM V_FiltrosPropiedades_ecomm i
                    WHERE i.IDPropiedad = fp.IDPropiedad);
GO
```